# Filling with previous values

Tags: postgresql

lets imagine that I have a table of fields quantity,price,discount. Here some of the entries in quantity are 0 correspondingly price and discount becomes 0. I would like to know how to copy the value of previous row to the row with entries 0 for price and discount, such that quantity will be 0 but price and discount shall never be 0.
likewise...!
i/p:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| quantity | price | discount |
+----------+-------+----------+
|       12 |   360 |       10 |
|        0 |     0 |        0 |
|        3 |    90 |        5 |
|        0 |     0 |        0 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

expected output:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| quantity | price | discount |
+----------+-------+----------+
|       12 |   360 |       10 |
|        0 |   360 |       10 |
|        3 |    90 |        5 |
|        0 |    90 |        5 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Please add an example (along with table definitions and sample data) and the expected output, as it stands it is hard to know what you're looking for.

Comment: In RDBMS "previous row" is not a thing unless you provide some ordering.

Comment: This is supposed to be the output. But seems to be a hard feat.

Comment: quantity should remain zero as it denotes no sales transactions but price and discount should be populated from the immediately previous row..like so.!!

Comment: table is product, its has an autoincremented primary key column as well. which I forgot to add.! APOLOGIES!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the previous row, you can use the `LAG` function:

```
> SELECT * FROM t;
┌────┬──────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ id │ quantity │ price │ discount │
├────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│  1 │       12 │   360 │       10 │
│  2 │        0 │     0 │        0 │
│  3 │        3 │    90 │        5 │
│  4 │        0 │     0 │        0 │
└────┴──────────┴───────┴──────────┘

> SELECT quantity,
         CASE price
           WHEN 0 THEN LAG(price) OVER (ORDER BY id) 
           ELSE price 
         END,
         CASE discount
           WHEN 0 THEN LAG(discount) OVER (ORDER BY id) 
           ELSE discount
         END
  FROM t;
┌──────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ quantity │ price │ discount │
├──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│       12 │   360 │       10 │
│        0 │   360 │       10 │
│        3 │    90 │        5 │
│        0 │    90 │        5 │
└──────────┴───────┴──────────┘
(4 rows)
```

Note that this only fetches the previous row, no the previous "non-zero" one, so you may still end up with rows having `0` for `discount` and/or `price`.

Comment: Thanks a tonne @Marth. Figured it out