# R - filling a cell with the value from the previous column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
x <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0)
y <- c(10:20)
dat <- rbind(x, y)
```

I don't want the X row to contain 0s. Instead, I would like to replace the 0s with the value from the most recent non-zero column.

The expected output is

```
1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     3     3
10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    19    20
```

This is similar to the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785495/filling-with-previous-values), but operating column-wise rather than row-wise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`, where we transpose the data, and use `fill` on all the column, transpose it back

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
     t %>% 
     as.data.frame %>% 
     na_if(., 0) %>% 
     fill(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))) %>%
     t
```

Answer (score 4):

step 1: *replace all zeros with `NA` because, ...*

```
dat[1, dat[1,] == 0] <- NA
```

step 2: *... you can then use a function that is esp. designed to do what you want with `NA`-values*

```
dat[1, ] <- zoo::na.locf(unlist(dat[1,]))

# dat[1, ] <- zoo::na.locf(dat[1, ])
```

result:

```
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
#x    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     3     3
#y   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    19    20
```

---

Since your example was a `matrix` and you possibly have a `data.frame` for your real data. Make sure you `?unlist` your data.frame-row into a vector, so `zoo::na.locf` can function as desired.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it's what I want. But when I use it on my actual dataset, I get "Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero", which I took to mean that the thing I'm trying to put in instead of an NA is empty (like I'm trying to sub an empty string in for an NA), and I'm not sure why that's the case since all the cells in that row are either a (non-empty) character string or NA.  Any insight?

Comment: Could you add data to your question that is more like your real data and where the solution fails?

Comment: @EmKayDee I have updated my solution. Please tell me if this now works for you.